# Why PCA is not considered in the taxonomy of blind source separation approaches?

Tags: pca, separation, independent-component-analysis

[Blind source separation (BSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_separation) approaches are divided in the literature into four methods, including [independent component analysis (ICA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis), [sparse component analysis (SCA)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226177109_Sparse_Component_Analysis_a_New_Tool_for_Data_Mining), and [non-negative matrix factorization (NMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_matrix_factorization).

[Principal component analysis (PCA)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4792409/) and ICA are similar. The former is based on the second-order moments ([variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance)/[covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)), and the latter uses [higher-order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_statistics). Both of them aim to find a mixing matrix $A$ to recover the original sources $S$ from a set of observations $X$, by the formula $S = AX$.

My question is why PCA is not considered as a blind source separation technique?

Comment: PCA doesn't seek to separate the sources into their original format, rather it presents them as the difference between two extremes. Blind source separation seeks to go further than PCA and return factors that are more comparable to the the original signals by exploiting properties of the original signal type, e.g. having no negatives weights in the factors.

Comment: Looks like there are papers in the literature that uses PCA or augmented versions as blind-source separation.  Such as https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/s0129065797000549  So I would assume that the classification is  historical that ICA is mentioned first and may not be generalised to rule out PCA (augmented) as  a blind source separation technique

Comment: @ReneBT thank you for your comment. In the literature, ICA is regarded as an extension of the nonlinear PCA. The standard formulation of both methods doesn't restrict the output to be non-negative as in NMF.

Comment: @MehmetSüzen, thank you, that's what confused me, in some references as in https://web.mit.edu/~gari/teaching/6.555/lectures/ch15_bss.pdf  the PCA is considered as a BSS technique in others it's not.